# signature does not match, bingx api in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sha256

Here's my code to generate a signature for bingx api and send a post request.
But i get error: signature does not match

My code:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const APIKEY = "My_API_Key";
const SECRETKEY = "My_Secret_key";

const getSign = () => {
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    const originString = `POST/api/v1/user/getBalanceapiKey=${APIKEY}&currency=USDT&timestamp=${timestamp}`;
    const b64Hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', SECRETKEY).update(originString).digest('base64');
    const urlB64Hmac = encodeURIComponent(b64Hmac).replace(/%2F/g, "/");
    return urlB64Hmac;
}

const genSignature = () => {

    const signature = getSign();
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    const url = `https://api-swap-rest.bingbon.pro/api/v1/user/getBalance`;

    const body = `apiKey=${APIKEY}&currency=USDT&timestamp=${timestamp}&sign=${signature}`;

    axios.post(url, body, { headers: {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}

genSignature();
```

Here's the Bingx api documentation: [Link](https://bingx-api.github.io/docs/swap/authentication.html#signature)